# How to access declared script fields from within classes in Groovy?

Tags: class, groovy, parameters

Let's say I have the next groovy code snippet:

```
def weightArg = args[0]

class Box {

   def width

   def height  

   def double weight() {
       //I want to return the value of weightArg here. How can I do that? 
   }
}
```

I want to let my class `Box` use some variables from its environment. What's the correct way to do it?

It seems that `weightArg` should be static and I should be able to get it from `Box` static initializer, but I cannot manage to overcome the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of whether it's "right" to do so or not, the way that you can access your weight variable from within the Box class is to simply remove the word "def".  The reason why is described [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Scoping+and+the+Semantics+of+%22def%22).

Answer (score 2):

Declaring a class in a middle of a script and making it dependent on scripts local variables is a definite sign of a bad design. If you can't design this whole system in OO way than stick to procedural programming. The main purpose of writing OO programs is factoring them to little independent pieces. In your case it's neither factoring, nor independent, and I'm pretty sure it has no purpose you could express in words.

In other words either don't declare a `Box` type at all or do it similar to this way:

```
class Box {
  Box(weight) { this.weight = weight }
  def width, height, weight
}
```

And use it like this:

```
def box = new Box(args[0])
```

Thus you get it abstracted from `weightArg` and `args[0]` and also become able to reuse it in different scenarios.

Otherwise you foredoom your program to be unmanageable and therefore dead after first revision. In decades of existence of OO programming it's been pretty much proven.

Another thing to note is that when you get a feeling that you need to introduce classes in your script it is a reliable sign that your program should be written as a normal application with packages and stuff - not as a script.

Comment: thanks for such a detailed answer! I have a fairly good experience in Java but I'm new to Groovy. So I'm experimenting on mixing paradigms. I'm not sure where should be method 'weight' declared. In Java I used to make everything a method, but now I think, that making it a closure with curried parameter will look groovier.

Comment: Being a Java developer you already know almost everything you should about programming in Groovy. Just do it the way you used to and simply replace the java's boilerplate code with groovy's concise solutions. Don't try to find any better paradigms 'cuz there are none. Groovy scripts are intended for really simple things which you're sure you don't have to test and you write them in half an hour. For your case I'd recommend writing a runnable class with a standard `main` method and use an args4j library.